# Удаление пробелов в строке в начале и в конце

Tags: javascript

Задача: не используя регулярные выражения, не используя метод trim, написать функцию которая удаляет пробелы вначале и в конце строки. Пробовал так, но удаляет все пробелы

```
function deleteSpace(string){
  let newStr = "*";

  for(elem of string){
    if(elem !== " "){
      newStr = newStr + elem;
    }
  };
  return newStr + "*";
}

console.log(deleteSpace(str))
```

Comment: Если подходить к условию формально, то можно и так: `.trimLeft().trimRight()` :)

Comment: к сожалению Trim'ы и регулярки использовать нельзя

Comment: `indexOf`, `lastIndexOf`

Comment: @Igor, не прокатит - найдет 0 и `length - 1` пробелы, а если строка на пробел не заканчивается, то вообще в середине строки `lastIndexOf`  найдет

Answer (score 2):

вариант 1:

```
while (string[0] == ' ')
    string = string.substr(1);
    
while (string[string.length - 1] == ' ')
    string = string.substr(0, string.length - 1);
```

вариант 2 (в принципе то же самое, но без заморочки и индекса):

```
while (string.startsWith(' '))
    string = string.substr(1);
    
while (string.endsWith(' '))
    string = string.substr(0, string.length - 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

Пара слов об эффективности. Лучше найти позиции для первого и последнего непробельных символов и вырезать подстроку один раз:

```
var myTrim = function(s) {
    var first = undefined;
    for (var i = 0; i < s.length; ++i) {
        if (s[i] !== ' ') {
            first = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (first === undefined) {
        return '';
    }

    var last;
    for (var i = s.length - 1; ; --i) {
        if (s[i] !== ' ') {
            last = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    return s.substring(first, last + 1);
};
```